# Using public class declared in a separate module

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

[image]

Very newbie problem. I have 2 vb modules: Form1.vb e Class2.vb

```
'Class2.vb
Public Class Class2
    ' code for class
end class
```

In the old IDE of Visual Studio I see this public class in all the project. With Visual Studio 2019 I cant see the class in Form1 module. I have to imports them?

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking the form and **View Code**?

Comment: I add printscreen in the post

Comment: Forms tend to store their code in `Partial Class` structures - usually, line 1 will read something like `Public Partial Class Form1`, though I haven't used VB in 2019, if I'm honest. The rest of the code will be in the form designer file.

Comment: There may be a setting that hides the start of partial classes (Tools > Options), but I'm just busy rebuilding my laptop at the moment, so I'm not sure!  Good luck :o)

Comment: I just tried that in VS2019 16.3.0 Preview 3.0 and couldn't reproduce the problem. If you simply type in `Class2.` with the dot, does IntelliSense offer anything?

Comment: There's also "Ctrl-Shift-R to force Visual Studio to refresh IntelliSense." as suggested in the comments at [Visual Studio IntelliSense Not Working? What To Do.](https://blog.submain.com/visual-studio-intellisense-not-working/#comment-478)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just redo the basics:

- Save
- Check if you are missing a project reference in case both classes are not in the same project.
- Try writing: "Dim a as New Class2"
- Try to compile and read the errors, if any.
- Save and reopen visual studio

Comment: Yes! The problem was different project file save!